# Change or delete GeoTiff - TAGs in TIFF-file

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff

I couldn't find a way, so far, to change GeoTiff-TAGs in my TIFF-file.
My OS is Linux Lubuntu 18.04 and I'm using Python 3.x.
Just EXIF-TAGs were possible to change via various approaches.

For both reading and writing the EXIF-TAGs, I could use e.g.:

- command-line tool: exiftool
- python-module: exifread
- python-module:  PIL
- python-module: tifffile
- python-module: skimage.external.tifffile

Especially the python-modules seem to be "blind on the eye" of GeoTiff-Tags, i.e. they read (and write) only the EXIF-TAGs, but not the GeoTiff-Tags.
With exiftool, I can at least read and printout the GeoTiff-TAGs along with the other ones.
For instance, a console output via exiftool of my TIFF-file, which includes the GeoTiff-Tags as well, would be:

Input:

`exiftool -D -G -a -u -U -f "newfile.tif"`

Output:

```
[ExifTool]          - ExifTool Version Number         : 10.80
[File]              - File Name                       : newfile.tif
[File]              - Directory                       : .
[File]              - File Size                       : 1503 kB
[File]              - File Modification Date/Time     : 2019:12:19 17:32:17+01:00
[File]              - File Access Date/Time           : 2019:12:19 17:32:17+01:00
[File]              - File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2019:12:19 17:32:17+01:00
[File]              - File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
[File]              - File Type                       : TIFF
[File]              - File Type Extension             : tif
[File]              - MIME Type                       : image/tiff
[File]              - Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
[File]              - Current IPTC Digest             : 79ffcf282ca6974ff99640a7421b40b7
[EXIF]            256 Image Width                     : 1148
[EXIF]            257 Image Height                    : 1337
[EXIF]            258 Bits Per Sample                 : 8
[EXIF]            259 Compression                     : Uncompressed
[EXIF]            262 Photometric Interpretation      : RGB Palette
[EXIF]            273 Strip Offsets                   : (Binary data 1390 bytes, use -b option to extract)
[EXIF]            274 Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
[EXIF]            277 Samples Per Pixel               : 1
[EXIF]            278 Rows Per Strip                  : 7
[EXIF]            279 Strip Byte Counts               : (Binary data 954 bytes, use -b option to extract)
[EXIF]            282 X Resolution                    : 1
[EXIF]            283 Y Resolution                    : 1
[EXIF]            284 Planar Configuration            : Chunky
[EXIF]            296 Resolution Unit                 : None
[EXIF]            305 Software                        : IMAGINE TIFF Support.Copyright 1991 - 1999 by ERDAS, Inc. All Rights Reserved.@(#)$RCSfile: etif.c $ $Revision: 1.11 $ $Date$
[EXIF]            320 Color Map                       : (Binary data 1536 bytes, use -b option to extract)
[EXIF]            339 Sample Format                   : Unsigned
[EXIF]          33550 Pixel Scale                     : 30 30 0
[EXIF]          33922 Model Tie Point                 : 0 0 0 1514925 1583985 0
[IPTC]             25 Keywords                        : word
[IPTC]              0 Application Record Version      : 4
[GeoTiff]           1 Geo Tiff Version                : 1.1.0
[GeoTiff]        1024 GT Model Type                   : Projected
[GeoTiff]        1025 GT Raster Type                  : Pixel Is Area
[GeoTiff]        1026 GT Citation                     : IMAGINE GeoTIFF Support.Copyright 1991 - 2001 by ERDAS, Inc. All Rights Reserved.@(#)$RCSfile: egtf.c $ $Revision: 1.11.2.3 $ $Date: 2004/11/24 09:12:56EST $.Projection Name = USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_USGS_version.Units = meters.GeoTIFF Units = meters
[GeoTiff]        2048 Geographic Type                 : NAD83
[GeoTiff]        3072 Projected CS Type               : User Defined
[GeoTiff]        3073 PCS Citation                    : IMAGINE GeoTIFF Support.Copyright 1991 - 2001 by ERDAS, Inc. All Rights Reserved.@(#)$RCSfile: egtf.c $ $Revision: 1.11.2.3 $ $Date: 2004/11/24 09:12:56EST $.Projection = Albers Conical Equal Area
[GeoTiff]        3074 Projection                      : User Defined
[GeoTiff]        3075 Proj Coord Trans                : Albers Equal Area
[GeoTiff]        3076 Proj Linear Units               : Linear Meter
[GeoTiff]        3078 Proj Std Parallel 1             : 29.5
[GeoTiff]        3079 Proj Std Parallel 2             : 45.5
[GeoTiff]        3081 Proj Nat Origin Lat             : 23
[GeoTiff]        3082 Proj False Easting              : 0
[GeoTiff]        3083 Proj False Northing             : 0
[GeoTiff]        3088 Proj Center Long                : -96
[Composite]         - Image Size                      : 1148x1337
[Composite]         - Megapixels                      : 1.5
```

Then, I tried like to change/delete e.g. the GeoTiff-TAG "Projection", which throws the following warning message without changing anything:
Input:

`exiftool "-Projection=" "newfile.tif"`

Output:

`Warning: Sorry, Projection is not writable. Nothing to do.`

On my search on the internet I've found other libraries and packages, which perhaps could help me out, but so far no avail, as I didn't find documentation, or it didn't work:

- libtiff (via command [tiffset](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tiffset), such as "tiffset -s Tag-Number Tag-Value dst-file", which changes/adds only EXIF-Tags, but doesn't touch the GeoTIFF-Tags)
- libgeotiff
- gdal_edit, gdal_translate (or gdal in general)

As for the latter approach, [gdal_edit](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html) and [gdal_translate](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html), I tried the following with no effect (even though there was no error-message whatsoever):

```
gdal_edit.py -mo "3075=Custom" "newfile.tif"
gdal_edit.py -mo "ProjCoordTrans=Custom" "newfile.tif"
gdal_translate -mo "3075=Custom" "newfile.tif" "newfile_2.tif"
gdal_translate -mo "ProjCoordTrans=Custom" "newfile.tif" "newfile_2.tif"
```

As you can see, in the example, I tried to modify the GeoTIFF-Tag number 3075, named "ProjCoordTrans" to a costum string. When carrying any of these 4 commands, no error was thrown, but checking afterwards the TIFF-Tags via

```
exiftool -D -G -a -u -U -f -s "newfile.tif"
```

I found the same TAG remained still unchanged.

**EDIT - Trying out rasterio:**

When trying to add a new TAG via the python library [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html),
as mentioned by Ryan [in his answer below](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/346043/155426),
it also doesn't resolve the issue as the newly added TAG is not assigned any TAG-number, and also rasterio captures only a few of the standard EXIF-TAGs, but none of the GeoTIFF-TAGs, wherefore unfortunately rasterio renders useless for this concern as well.

```
import rasterio

filename = '/home/andylu/Desktop/Models_Master/AERSURFACE/Input/Play_around_with_exiftools/playaround_file.tif'
savefilename = '/home/andylu/Desktop/Models_Master/AERSURFACE/Input/Play_around_with_exiftools/playaround_file_mod.tif'

with rasterio.open(filename, 'r') as src_ds:
    tags = src_ds.tags()

    print("\nTags BEFORE changing:\n{}".format(tags))

    with rasterio.open(savefilename, 'w', **src_ds.meta) as dst_ds:
        tags['NEWTAG'] = 'NEW VALUE'
        dst_ds.update_tags(**tags)
        dst_ds.write(src_ds.read())


with rasterio.open(savefilename, 'r') as src_ds:
    tags = src_ds.tags()

    print("\nTags AFTER changing:\n{}".format(tags))


Tags BEFORE changing:
{'3075': 'Custom', 'AREA_OR_POINT': 'Area', 'ProjCoordTrans': 'Custom', 'TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT': '1 (unitless)', 'TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE': 'Custom Bla 2', 'TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION': '1', 'TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION': '1'}

Tags AFTER changing:
{'3075': 'Custom', 'AREA_OR_POINT': 'Area', 'NEWTAG': 'NEW VALUE', 'ProjCoordTrans': 'Custom', 'TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT': '1 (unitless)', 'TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE': 'Custom Bla 2', 'TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION': '1', 'TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION': '1'}
```

Afterwards, double-check the changes via exiftool as follows
(note the rather random allocation of the newly added tag "NEWTAG" in between the EXIF and GeoTIFF-tags):

```
(base) andylu@andylu-ThinkPad-Edge-E130:~/Desktop/Models_Master/AERSURFACE/Input/Play_around_with_exiftools$ exiftool -D -G -a -u -U -f playaround_file_mod.tif

[ExifTool]          - ExifTool Version Number         : 10.80
[File]              - File Name                       : playaround_file_mod.tif
[File]              - Directory                       : .
[File]              - File Size                       : 1501 kB
[File]              - File Modification Date/Time     : 2020:01:10 18:01:06+01:00
[File]              - File Access Date/Time           : 2020:01:10 18:01:06+01:00
[File]              - File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2020:01:10 18:01:06+01:00
[File]              - File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
[File]              - File Type                       : TIFF
[File]              - File Type Extension             : tif
[File]              - MIME Type                       : image/tiff
[File]              - Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
[EXIF]            256 Image Width                     : 1148
[EXIF]            257 Image Height                    : 1337
[EXIF]            258 Bits Per Sample                 : 8
[EXIF]            259 Compression                     : Uncompressed
[EXIF]            262 Photometric Interpretation      : BlackIsZero
[EXIF]            273 Strip Offsets                   : (Binary data 1387 bytes, use -b option to extract)
[EXIF]            277 Samples Per Pixel               : 1
[EXIF]            278 Rows Per Strip                  : 7
[EXIF]            279 Strip Byte Counts               : (Binary data 954 bytes, use -b option to extract)
[EXIF]            282 X Resolution                    : 1
[EXIF]            283 Y Resolution                    : 1
[EXIF]            284 Planar Configuration            : Chunky
[EXIF]            296 Resolution Unit                 : None
[EXIF]            305 Software                        : Custom Bla 2
[EXIF]            339 Sample Format                   : Unsigned
[EXIF]          33550 Pixel Scale                     : 30 30 0
[EXIF]          33922 Model Tie Point                 : 0 0 0 1514925 1583985 0
[EXIF]          42112 GDAL Metadata                   : <GDALMetadata>.  <Item name="3075">Custom</Item>.  <Item name="NEWTAG">NEW VALUE</Item>.  <Item name="ProjCoordTrans">Custom</Item>.</GDALMetadata>.
[GeoTiff]           1 Geo Tiff Version                : 1.1.0
[GeoTiff]        1024 GT Model Type                   : Projected
[GeoTiff]        1025 GT Raster Type                  : Pixel Is Area
[GeoTiff]        1026 GT Citation                     : USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_USGS_version
[GeoTiff]        2048 Geographic Type                 : NAD83
[GeoTiff]        2049 Geog Citation                   : NAD83
[GeoTiff]        2054 Geog Angular Units              : Angular Degree
[GeoTiff]        2057 Geog Semi Major Axis            : 6378137
[GeoTiff]        2059 Geog Inv Flattening             : 298.257222101004
[GeoTiff]        3072 Projected CS Type               : User Defined
[GeoTiff]        3074 Projection                      : User Defined
[GeoTiff]        3075 Proj Coord Trans                : Albers Equal Area
[GeoTiff]        3076 Proj Linear Units               : Linear Meter
[GeoTiff]        3078 Proj Std Parallel 1             : 29.5
[GeoTiff]        3079 Proj Std Parallel 2             : 45.5
[GeoTiff]        3080 Proj Nat Origin Long            : -96
[GeoTiff]        3081 Proj Nat Origin Lat             : 23
[GeoTiff]        3082 Proj False Easting              : 0
[GeoTiff]        3083 Proj False Northing             : 0
[Composite]         - Image Size                      : 1148x1337
```

I'd like to know if there is a possibility to change GeoTiff-Tags. There must be a possibility.

Comment: Have you tried the metadata example in https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html?

Comment: @user30184, I've tried to change an example GeoTIFF-Tag of my file with both gdal_edit and gdal_translate without success (see edited version of my question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found an [answer](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=10685.0) on the project-page of exiftool itself.
Hereafter, I'll summarize what I found out with the kind help of the page-author [Phil Harvey](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?action=profile;u=1).

To copy all GeoTiff tags from one file to another, do this:

```
exiftool -tagsfromfile SRCFILE -GeoTiffDirectory -GeoTiffDoubleParams -GeoTiffAsciiParams DSTFILE
```

That does the trick.
I assume that those pseudo-TAGs are split-up by exiftools in all sub-GeoTiff-TAGs, because other tools in python print these out as TAGs with their associated numbers.
Python packages which are able to display these general 3 Geotiff-TAGs

- ('34735') 'GeoKeyDirectoryTag'
- ('34736') 'GeoDoubleParamsTag'
- ('34737') 'GeoAsciiParamsTag'

are for example:

```
import PIL
import tifffile as tf
from skimage.external import tifffile as sk_tf
```

An example output using PILLOW (PIL) via my python script applied on an example TIFF would be:

```
...
** GENERIC APPROACH USING PILLOW-package **

TAG number: '254'
TAG name: 'NewSubfileType'
TAG value: '(0,)'

TAG number: '256'
TAG name: 'ImageWidth'
TAG value: '(2388,)'

TAG number: '257'
TAG name: 'ImageLength'
TAG value: '(1651,)'

TAG number: '258'
TAG name: 'BitsPerSample'
TAG value: '(8,)'

TAG number: '259'
TAG name: 'Compression'
TAG value: '(1,)'

TAG number: '262'
TAG name: 'PhotometricInterpretation'
TAG value: '(1,)'

TAG number: '270'
TAG name: 'ImageDescription'
TAG value: '('{"shape": [1651, 2388]}',)'

TAG number: '274'
TAG name: 'Orientation'
TAG value: '(1,)'

TAG number: '277'
TAG name: 'SamplesPerPixel'
TAG value: '(1,)'

TAG number: '278'
TAG name: 'RowsPerStrip'
TAG value: '(1651,)'

TAG number: '282'
TAG name: 'XResolution'
TAG value: '((1, 1),)'

TAG number: '283'
TAG name: 'YResolution'
TAG value: '((1, 1),)'

TAG number: '284'
TAG name: 'PlanarConfiguration'
TAG value: '(1,)'

TAG number: '296'
TAG name: 'ResolutionUnit'
TAG value: '(1,)'

TAG number: '305'
TAG name: 'Software'
TAG value: '('tifffile.py',)'

TAG number: '339'
TAG name: 'SampleFormat'
TAG value: '(1,)'

TAG number: '33550'
TAG name: 'ModelPixelScaleTag'
TAG value: '(30.0, 30.0, 0.0)'

TAG number: '33922'
TAG name: 'ModelTiepointTag'
TAG value: '(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 737125.0, 4328658.0, 0.0)'

TAG number: '34735'
TAG name: 'GeoKeyDirectoryTag'
TAG value: '(1, 1, 0, 15, 1024, 0, 1, 1, 1025, 0, 1, 1, 1026, 34737, 266, 0, 2048, 0, 1, 4269, 3072, 0, 1, 32767, 3073, 34737, 197, 266, 3074, 0, 1, 32767, 3075, 0, 1, 11, 3076, 0, 1, 9001, 3078, 34736, 1, 0, 3079, 34736, 1, 1, 3081, 34736, 1, 2, 3082, 34736, 1, 3, 3083, 34736, 1, 4, 3088, 34736, 1, 5)'

TAG number: '34736'
TAG name: 'GeoDoubleParamsTag'
TAG value: '(29.5, 45.5, 23.0, 0.0, 0.0, -96.0)'

TAG number: '34737'
TAG name: 'GeoAsciiParamsTag'
TAG value: '('IMAGINE GeoTIFF Support\nCopyright 1991 - 2001 by ERDAS, Inc. All Rights Reserved\n@(#)$RCSfile: egtf.c $ $Revision: 1.11.2.3 $ $Date: 2004/11/24 09:12:56EST $\nProjection Name = USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_USGS_version\nUnits = meters\nGeoTIFF Units = meters|IMAGINE GeoTIFF Support\nCopyright 1991 - 2001 by ERDAS, Inc. All Rights Reserved\n@(#)$RCSfile: egtf.c $ $Revision: 1.11.2.3 $ $Date: 2004/11/24 09:12:56EST $\nProjection = Albers Conical Equal Area|',)'
...
```

To change the Projection tag alone, you would currently have to manually edit the GeoTiffDirectory data.

First write the (binary) data to a file:

```
exiftool -geotiffdirectory -b FILE.tif > out.dat
```

Then find the offset of e.g. the Projection value, like:

```
exiftool FILE.tif -v3 | grep -A 2 Projection -
  | 9)  Projection = 16017
  |     - Tag 0x0c02 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         0056: 3e 91                                           [>.]
```

--> Edit bytes 0x56 and 0x57 in out.dat to change to whatever projection you want, then put the modified GeoTiff directory back into the TIFF file:

```
exiftool "-geotiffdirectory<=out.dat" FILE.tif
```

Nevertheless, it is important to note, that changing the 3 crucial summarizing GeoTIFF-Tags, instead of trying to manipulate one of the single GeoTIFF-TAGs via modifying the above-mentioned binary-file and reassign it to the TIFF in question,  could be more effective.

For the sake of completion, these 3 GeoTIFF-Tags were:

- ('34735') 'GeoKeyDirectoryTag'
- ('34736') 'GeoDoubleParamsTag'
- ('34737') 'GeoAsciiParamsTag'

Nevertheless, it could be possible that by changing just one specific GeoTIFF-Tag within the binary-file is also going to update as a result the 3 crucial GeoTIFF-summary-Tags in new TIFF.
I haven't tried that out yet.

If you have to add some additional information or experiences with these approaches, which work for you etc., let me know.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I like to use [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) in python to manipulate metadata [tags](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/tags.html). Here is a rough example:

```py
import rasterio

with rasterio.open('raster.tif', 'r') as src_ds:
    tags = src_ds.tags()
    with rasterio.open('newraster.tif', 'w', **src_ds.meta) as dst_ds:
        tags['NEWTAG'] = 'NEW VALUE'
        dst_ds.update_tags(**tags)
        dst_ds.write(src_ds.read())
```

That will create a new raster with the same tags as the original, but with a new/modified tag `NEWTAG`. I'm not sure if this will allow to change EXIF tags, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Hey Ryan, thanks for your comment. I edited my post including the try with rasterio. I tried out the python library rasterio as you said, which is like the only library I haven't tried so far. It also didn't work, unfortunately.